# How to migrate name column to first and last name in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, database-migration

I want to write an SQL migration to split a "name" column to a "first_name" and a "last_name" column in a "users" table, I have already created the 2 columns.

I am looking for a command that looks like

```sql
UPDATE users
SET (first_name, last_name)
VALUES ({expression for first name}, {expression for last name});
```

I am accepting the assumption that the frontier between the 2 parts is the first whitespace character. (i.e. for John Doe Jr, the last name should be 'Doe Jr')

I have tried to use `regexp_match(name, [^\s]*)` for the first name but for `name="John Doe"` it returns `first_name="{John}"`, how could I fix this, or is there a better way than  using `regexp_match`?

Comment: Also, watch for things like Doe, John - John Doe Jr - Mr John E Doe - Doe, Mr John E Esq. - etc.

Comment: the users will be able to edit their names so i'm going with the assumption that split at the first whitespace is OK to make it simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE users SET first_name = (regexp_split_to_array(name, E'\s+'))[1], last_name = (regexp_split_to_array(name, E'\s+'))[2]
```

for names where 2 and more last names

```
update users set firstname = (regexp_split_to_array(name, E'\\s+'))[1], 
        lastname = array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(name, E'\\s+'))[2:], ' ')
```

Comment: for "John Doe Jr" wouldn't this result in `first_name='John'` and `last_name='Doe'`, how could I have `last_name='Doe Jr'` ? this is especially important for users with a Hispanic origin where it is common to have 2 last names

Comment: @ussu updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this using `(regexp_match(name, '[^\s]*'))[1]` but I'm not sure if it's the most idiomatic SQL